# Probability of Random Variable Minus Mean greater k

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I found the following exercise in an online forum but my solution does not match with one of the given answer choices:

Let $X$ be a random variable on $\mathbb{R}$ sucht that $P[X<1]=0$, $P[X>e]=0$, and for $y\in[1,e]$, $P[X<y]=\displaystyle\int^y_1\frac{1}{x}dx$. Let $\mu$ denote the mean value of $X$.
What value of $\kappa$ satisfies $P[X-\mu > \kappa]=0.05$?

---

The first thing I did was to calculate the mean value: $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X] = \displaystyle\int^e_1x\frac{1}{x}dx=e-1$

Next, I calculated the probability as follows: $P[X-\mu > \kappa] = 1-P[X < \kappa+\mu] = \displaystyle1 - \int_1^{\kappa+\mu}\frac{1}{x}dx \overset{!}{=} 0.05$

Therefore I get $\kappa = e^{0.95}+1-e=0.867$

---

The following answer options are given:

- 0.80
- 0.85
- 0.90
- 0.95
- 0.99

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I get the same value you got.  Only guess I have is that they meant to indicate that you were to round your answer.

Comment: What is the link of the source?